# Error with Contextify and Node Gyp when installing react 16 with node 8 LTS

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I upgraded from React 15 and Node 6 to React 16 and Node 8. When I tried to do `npm install`, it fails with contextify module which is required by some dependencies, not mine. The contextify module tries to install node-gyp in my Mac High Seria and it's failing with missing some C function in Node 8. When I downgraded to node 6, contextify and node-gyp plays along well but React 16 is not supported. Have anyone succeeded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked my dependencies with `npm list` and found that contextify is not actually needed. It is one of the dependencies of another module which is not needed. So I removed the module and it's working now.